# Left Insider Program but still receiving Insider updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider, windows-11-preview

I enabled windows insider program, it worked fine for a while, then windows 11 came and my laptop keep trying to update to windows 11. thing my laptop does not have TPM 2.0, so I can't install windows 11 but windows keep taking me into pc check thing. so I left the insider program

[image: screenshot: windows insider program]

Still to make sure, I clicked that "leave the insider program" link, it took me to Microsoft website and this is what it said:

Email is not registered
[image: screenshot: email is not registered]

As you can see, I left, but on windows updates it still says I have set up my device for insider builds.

Your device is set up to get insider preview builds
[image: screenshot: Your device is set up to get insider preview builds]

Now every few days it tries to download windows 11 and ends the process with this error

[image: screenshot: error encountered]

Does anyone know how to disable this resolve this issue?

Comment: What build are you running exactly? [Edit] your question so I can answer your question. I have a theory on what’s going on but I can’t say for certain without the specific your currently running.

Comment: @Ramhound im not running any build, i just enabled it and then got this error so i disabled it.

Comment: Impossible; You have to be running Windows 10; Can you run *winver* and post the exact build it says your running? There is absolutely a reason I want to see which build of Windows 10 you are your running. I am trying to give you an answer other than “reinstall Windows 10” and actually answer the question you have asked but I cannot do that without know which Windows 10 build you are running.  Your comment makes me believe you think I am asking which Insider Build you are running, I did not, just provide me the information if you don’t mind.

Comment: @Ramhound i ran the command and it says Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1466)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you will have to use the ISO method to upgrade to 21H2, that should solve your insider preview.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for telling me about 21H2, i downloaded windows update assistant from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), it gave me option to update to 21H2 and i did, took 6 hours to finish but atleast that annoying windows 11 preview build is gone. thank you so much!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not opt into the Insider Preview , not that it matters, since your on the last version of Windows 10 now that your on 21H2

Comment: @Ramhound yeah i won't join it again, there isn't much for me in it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure after you left the program, that you have restarted your computer.

In the Windows Insider Program, once you have begun and have an Insider build, there are only two ways out.

1. Wait until the Production build reaches the Insider Build.  At that point (unknown as to exactly when) you will be back in Production.
2. More direct:  Back everything up and install Windows 10 Production or Windows 11 Production and restore your programs and data.

This is how Insider Program works with respect to exiting the program after you have started and run some updates.

Comment: but i didn't run any update, it was just turn on and off thing. i dont mind if it keep bugging me about windows 10 updates, i have windows 10 so no problem with that. it's just this annoying windows 11 pc check i dont want, when my laptop doesn't meet the requirement then it should just give up but it keep going in a loop.

Comment: Make double sure you truly left the Insider Program.  Restart, Wait until next Patch Tuesday (2 to 3 weeks) and see if you go properly back to Windows 10.

Comment: yes, i have. you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUWD.png). it's been like this since the release of windows 11, i dont think anything will change in 2-3 weeks

Comment: If you do not wish to wait or don't think the wait will be successful (cannot say) then you may need to reinstall Windows 10